# C++ how to make a virtual funtion return any type of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions

Lets say i have a class(foo) that has an interger and a character. I want to be able to fill in this data with information loaded from a file, so I added a load function that returns a pointer of one of foo's member variables (based on an ID) to an object that then sets it to the value loaded from the file. I could use an auto return type in this case, but I want the funtion to be virtual so that deprived classes can use different ID's in the case they have more variables. I know I could use a void pointer, but I wish to avoid using one.

Comment: would templates help you?

Comment: Assuming it was possible to do this, how would you expect the caller to work out what type was returned?

Comment: `std::variant` or `std::any` might help, but not sure that you should do what you want...

Comment: Not exactly what you describe, but you might want to take a look at [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Can you add some code in addition to plain English so that the answerers can understand your idea better?

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a good use case for `virtual`, because you call a `virtual` member through a base class pointer with its argument and return type, and it works according to the type of the derived instance at runtime.  The `virtual` member can’t return a whole bunch of different things or even be called in different ways. Those are different overloaded functions with static dispatch.

If you need a bunch of different members that take and return `char`, `int` or other types, you’d want to write them as separate overloaded functions, or possibly as a non-`virtual` template, such as `template <typename T> T* foo::bar(const T&);`.

If what you need is to return a pointer that could be to any type of object, that should be a pointer to their common base class. If there really isn’t one, the rules of the language do allow you to cast a `void*` to any type of object pointer, but (as you said) that’s a code smell.